# Googlemaps react component - to handle multiple maps on the same page avoid error - "included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have a googlemaps component - that works if its the only one on the page -- when I try and make different instances of the component -- or use it as a field widget (a field which is a clickable map that stashes lat/lng and location data) and its seen multiple times - I keep getting the same google api error

[image]

---

also with react - what is the best practice and using the api keys -- do I put them in an env file - where - and how would you read this file -- currently the api key is hardbaked into the component itself.

I get this error sometimes - when just switching between two pages that may feature a map?
"You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

[image]

I see there is an npm module - but I don't want to necessarily re-implement this when I already built the code in the component and may find it has the same issue with multiple maps or complaining multiple maps have been called -- should the loader be called once and stored in a cookie or something?

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import {Loader, LoaderOptions} from 'google-maps';

import axios from 'axios';

import './GoogleMapsMarkers.scss';

class GoogleMapsMarkers extends Component {  
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

    let apiKey = "*************************";

    this.state = {
      apiKey: apiKey,
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderMap();
  }
  
  renderMap(){
    let that = this;
    let $this = this.myRef.current;
    const options: LoaderOptions = {};

    const loader = new Loader(this.state.apiKey, options);
    loader.load().then(function (google) {
      let map = new google.maps.Map($this, {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.909736, -38.522109),
          zoom: 2,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true,
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < that.props.markers.length-1; i++) {

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(
            that.props.markers[i].lat,
            that.props.markers[i].lng
          ),
          map: map,
          title: that.props.markers[i].name,
        });

      }


    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <div 
          ref={this.myRef} 
          className="googlemaps"
      ></div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({  }, dispatch);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GoogleMapsMarkers));
```

---

```
let markers = [
    {
      name: "George",
      lat: "45.0000",
      lng: "-1.00"
    },
    {
      name: "Kevin",
      lat: "50.897498792713989",
      lng: "-1.0782727519911006"
    }
  ];

<GoogleMapsMarkers markers={markers} />
```

Working sandbox that demonstrates the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-murdock-pbneqh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a working codesandbox that we can take a look at?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-murdock-pbneqh?file=/src/App.js  it breaks if you add multiple instances of the component -- got to get your own googlemap api key for this

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox. Can you also provide if there's a library that you used for this? I can't seem to find a documentation regarding how you were implementing google maps on your React app.

Comment: There is no lib - I just got it working with the api key as standard. I am unsure though if or which lib - could work and overcome this google maps multiple maps issue - it may be a built in limit.

Comment: I checked the network tab after loading your sample app and I can see that your code both loaded: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=_dk_google_maps_loader_cb&key=*************************` and `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i17&2i263&2e1&3u2&4m2&1u770&2u250&5m6&1e0&5sen-US&6sus&10b1&12b1&14i1379903&key=*************************&token=94408`. While I can understand what the first URL is, which is used to load Maps Javascript, but I don't understand why you have a URL for loading Static Maps using Javascript.

Comment: I found out that you used [google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps?activeTab=readme) JS loader which is pretty much outdated already, so I'm assuming that this is causing an issue. My suggestion for now is that you use the [latest JS API Loaders in this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries-open-source#loading_the_api) and see if the issue is still apparent. You can try using the `react-wrapper`.

Comment: I did wonder if it was the loader - that maybe it needs to be invoked once and stashed in a cookie or something and then used for all other maps henceforth - I wonder if there is a way of installing that npm in the sandbox and testing the idea. I wasn't sure if there was a google map react module that solves this problem either.

Comment: codesandbox would be fine, you just have to include the npm module on the dependencies.